# Type annotation for `this` keyword in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a standalone function that's meant to use the context provided by `Function.prototype.call`.

For example:

```
function foo () {
    return this.bar;
}

> foo.call({bar: "baz"})
baz
```

Is there a way to provide a Typescript type annotation for the `this` keyword in this scenario?

Comment: it has a type that being `any`. Which in this case is also the correct type since the function could be called with any object. If you'd want more restrictive type you could just get the object as a parameter and type it that way.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all, you can use the special [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) syntax to identify the type of object you expect `this` to be:

```
function foo (this: {bar: string}) {
    return this.bar; // no more error
}
```

which helps if you call it directly:

```
foo(); // error, this is undefined, not {bar: string}

var barHaver = { bar: "hello", doFoo: foo };
barHaver.doFoo(); // acceptable, since barHaver.bar is a string

var carHaver = { car: "hello", doFoo: foo };
carHaver.doFoo(); // unacceptable, carHaver.bar is undefined
```

---

UPDATE for TS3.2+

TypeScript 3.2 introduced [the `--strictBindCallApply` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#strictbindcallapply) which strongly types the .call() method of functions.  If you use this (or [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) which includes this), then the `this` parameter will also enforce that `foo.call()` behave as desired:

```
foo.call({ bar: "baz" }); // okay
foo.call({ baz: "quux" }); // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUUAWMDOAuRAb0QCMBDAJwJygpjAHNEBfASiIChFEKBTKEBSRZcAOnIUA3IgD0MxGDiIAtnD6JeFCmo7MO+lOlbS5GrWoA0iETkS5E4ACa9g9Xo6uKoRCdVr0GPQ4AN0pSSgAJMmDNRABeInCqRAAiTF4AGwy4FKtHOAAxVAJDFkkOCSiYilF8oqMTeTIICF4ABygyEgzeKxx6VqSqzXEw+zJEGjpGfVCKRAhI6NiE4kXktMzs3MQ64uRUMo514Zq9htl5cGbWjq6eqxPlmok7WycXN0d9DkNRRayaGIvlS5AAXikWMZLog4ABrMgAT1+qH+ZEBwLIYIIKQAjiAQAAPSFsRpmbQUACEHCAA)

---

pre TS3.2 answer follows:

But you want to use `foo.call()`.  Unfortunately the `Function.prototype.call()` typing in TypeScript won't really enforce this restriction for you:

```
foo.call({ bar: "baz" }); // okay, but
foo.call({ baz: "quux" }); // no error, too bad!
```

Merging something better into TypeScript's `Function` declaration caused me problems, (First point of ugliness; you will need to cast `foo` to something) so you can try something like this:

```
interface ThisFunction<T extends {} = {}, R extends any = any, A extends any = any> {
  (this: T, ...args: A[]): R;
  call(thisArg: T, ...args: A[]): R;
}
```

A `ThisFunction<T,R,A>` is a function with a `this` of type `T`, a return value of type `R`, and a rest argument of type `A[]`. (Second point of ugliness: you can't easily specify multiple arguments of different types in a way that will be enforced by the type system.)

You can then cast `foo` to `ThisFunction<{ bar: string }, string>`, (Third point of ugliness: the type system just will not infer `this` types) and then finally use `call()`:

```
(<ThisFunction<{ bar: string }, string>>foo).call({ bar: "baz" }); // okay, and
(<ThisFunction<{ bar: string }, string>>foo).call({ baz: "quux" }); // error, hooray!
```