# Let TypeScript know that a function is bound to an HTMLElement and not the current object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following setup of `interfaces` and `types`:

```
export interface MyEventMap extends ElementEventMap {
  'loaded': Event
}

export type MyEventsTypes = {
  [key in keyof (HTMLElementEventMap & MyEventMap)]?: (e: Event) => void
}

export interface ObectInterface {
  events?: MyEventsTypes
}
```

When I try and use the `ObjectInterface`, within the `loaded` function I get this error:

> Property 'textContent' does not exist on type 'MyEventsTypes'.

How can I make it so that typescript knows that `this` is bound to an `HTMLElement` and not `MyEventsTypes`? When I compile my code, and `loaded` runs, `this.textContent` works just fine, and displays the text.

```
<ObjectInterface>{
  events: {
    loaded() {
      console.log(this.textContent)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type annotation for \`this\` keyword in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242125/type-annotation-for-this-keyword-in-typescript) or [Declaring the type of 'this' in a typescript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28920753)

Comment: change `(e: Event) => void` to `(this: HTMLElement, e: Event) => void` ?